# Sort a data frame by group sum first, then by frequency

Tags: r

I have the following data in a data.frame:

```
reg        id    n
Echo       E1    7
Charlie    C1    3
Alpha      A1    5
Echo       E2    1
Alpha      A2    4
Charlie    C2    9
```

I am trying to sort it by reg sum first, then by n (both decreasing).
The result would be:

```
reg        id    n
Charlie    C2    9
Charlie    C1    3
Alpha      A1    5
Alpha      A2    4
Echo       E1    7
Echo       E2    1
```

Because Charlie has 12, Alpha has 9 and Echo has 8.

So far, I've only been able to group and do the second part of the sorting (through poor use of dplyr). The reg column still gets sorted alphabetically.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr

```
# data
df1 <- read.table(text = "reg        id    n
Echo       E1    7
Charlie    C1    3
Alpha      A1    5
Echo       E2    1
Alpha      A2    4
Charlie    C2    9", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(reg) %>% 
  mutate(nSum = sum(n)) %>% 
  arrange(-nSum, -n) %>% 
  select(-nSum)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: reg [3]
# 
#       reg     id     n
#    <fctr> <fctr> <int>
# 1 Charlie     C2     9
# 2 Charlie     C1     3
# 3   Alpha     A1     5
# 4   Alpha     A2     4
# 5    Echo     E1     7
# 6    Echo     E2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider calculating the group sum with `ave()` then sort both columns, filtering out sum column:

```
df <- df[with(transform(df, sum=ave(df$n, df$reg, FUN=sum)), order(-sum, -n)), c(1:3)]
row.names(df) <- seq_len(nrow(df))

df

#       reg id n
# 1 Charlie C2 9
# 2 Charlie C1 3
# 3   Alpha A1 5
# 4   Alpha A2 4
# 5    Echo E1 7
# 6    Echo E2 1
```

Comment: I like the idea - you could squish it up I think with `dat[with(dat, order(ave(n, reg, FUN=sum), n, decreasing=TRUE)),]` or even `dat[with(dat, order(-ave(n, reg, FUN=sum), -n)),]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, n1:= sum(n) , by = reg][order(-n1, -n)][, n1:= NULL][]
#       reg id n
#1: Charlie C2 9
#2: Charlie C1 3
#3:   Alpha A1 5
#4:   Alpha A2 4
#5:    Echo E1 7
#6:    Echo E2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
df[with(df, order(-ave(df$n, df$reg, FUN=sum), -n)),]
      reg id n
6 Charlie C2 9
2 Charlie C1 3
3   Alpha A1 5
5   Alpha A2 4
1    Echo E1 7
4    Echo E2 1
```